# Why would an interface override methods of the interface(s) it extends in Java 7?

Tags: java, interfaces, standard-library

I was looking at [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#entrySet()) documentation from Java 7 and I have realized that `SortedMap`, which extends `Map` overrides `entrySet()`, `keySet()` and `values()`.

AFAIK, interfaces cannot implement a method in Java prior to Java 8. So what was the reason for overriding these methods?

Answer (score 6):

It looks as though the methods were overridden solely so that different documentation could be provided.

For all three methods, the only difference in documentation is that the `SortedMap` version adds "The set's iterator returns the entries in ascending key order." to the main description and "sorted in ascending key order" to the return value description.

---

P.S. The obvious follow-up question is why weren't these three method signatures simply changed to return `SortedSet` instead of `Set`. Unfortunately I can't come up with a reason for this, as the Java language seems to allow this sort of change, and the additional methods on `SortedSet` seem trivial to implement.

Comment: returning SortedSet was not allowed when this interface was introduced. SortedMap javadoc says it's there since Java 1.2 while [covariant returns](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/covariant_return_types_in_java) were introduced only in Java 1.5

Comment: If it is for the purpose of documentation (a reasonable guess), it's funny that it makes part of the docs _more_ confusing:  the "Methods inherited from interface..." section just seems wrong.  This is particularly true with List -- most of the methods inherited from Collection are "overridden".

Answer (score 4):

From the [Java Language Spec for Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1.1):

> About all that can be accomplished by an overriding method declaration, other than to affirm a method signature, is to refine the return type or to restrict the exceptions that might be thrown by an implementation of the method.

So: You can change the `throws` signature, and/or you can specify a more specific sub-type of the original return type. For example:

```
interface Foo {
  Foo get() throws IOException;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  Bar get() throws RuntimeException;
}
```

Is completely legal, as would be omitting the `throws` clause completely for either one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any such thing as interface methods being able to "override" parent interface methods (in Java 7); only (sub) classes can have "override" methods.  SortedMap and Map are interfaces not classes.  Therefore, what you're seeing is merely a documentation issue, rather than some technical issue.

(And overloading by sub-interfaces is another story, though the methods you're citing are not overloads as they have the same signature.)